# Give full path to a variable with part of the path name?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

This is a better version including what I have done so far:

This dictionary: `sfiles`

```
{'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\05052\\ASTTOM\\ASTTOM': [], 
'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\05052\\ASTIK\\ASTIK': [], 
'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\05052\\ROADS\\ROADS': []}
```

I want to check if `sh1` is in there:

```
sh1
u'ASTTOM'
```

and

```
sh2
u'ASTIK'
```

I want to assign to sh1 the full path from the `sfiles` that matches.

What I did :

```
   for i in list(sfiles):
       if shape1 in os.path.basename(i):
            print((i))
            shape1 = i
```

Is this approach correct and how can I do the same efficiently for the sh2?

Comment: you can use `os.path.basename` instead of splitting. And looking in the keys of dictionaries for substrings isn't a very efficient method. create a dictionary with basename as key, and full path (if needed) + list. Then lookup is instant.

Comment: Can you suggest a way to do the sh1 and sh2 check and assignment with the full paths? Maybe with zip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `for i in list(sfiles)`, the `i` is not the index to the list, but already assigned to each of the elements in turn, so your loop has to be just:

```
for i in list(sfiles):
    if shape1 in i.split('\\')[-1]:
        print(i)
        …
```

> how can I do the same efficiently for the sh2?

Define a function containing your loop and pass `sh1` or `sh2` as the argument, e. g.:

```
def matching(shape):
    for i in list(sfiles):
        if shape in i.split('\\')[-1]:
            return i
```

> to assign to sh1 the full path from the sfiles that matches

```
sh1 = matching(sh1)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to do the sh1 and sh2 parts?

Comment: @user10528055 - I amended the answer.

Comment: do you think a zip with for i , j in list(sfiles).. would be ok?

Comment: @user10528055 - We cannot unpack `list(sfiles)` into two `for` variables.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you want to find what path has sh1 (called shape1) in its last part. 
So, you can do it like this:

```
sfiles = {'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\05052\\ASTTOM\\ASTTOM': [],
          'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\05052\\ASTIK\\ASTIK': [],
          'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\05052\\ROADS\\ROADS': []
          }

for pth in sfiles.keys():
    if shape1 in pth.split("\\")[-1]:
       print(pth)
```

Answer (score 0):

you're not really using your dictionary. I suggest that you rebuild another dictionary with the file *name* as key (using `os.path.basename`, not `str.split`), leaving the full path and the list as a tuple of values

```
import os

data = {'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\05052\\ASTTOM\\ASTTOM': [],
'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\05052\\ASTIK\\ASTIK': [],
'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\05052\\ROADS\\ROADS': []}

new_data = {os.path.basename(path): (path,value) for path,value in data.items()}
```

how it looks like:

```
>>> new_data
{'ASTIK': ('C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\05052\\ASTIK\\ASTIK', []),
 'ASTTOM': ('C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\05052\\ASTTOM\\ASTTOM', []),
 'ROADS': ('C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\05052\\ROADS\\ROADS', [])}
```

Then you can have `O(1)` lookup and test:

```
shape1 = "ASTIK"
print(shape1 in new_data,new_data.get(shape1))
```

prints:

```
True ('C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\05052\\ASTIK\\ASTIK', [])
```

(because the value is in the dictionary, and `get` retrieves the data

Comment: You refer to the previous version of the code in the question probably because as it is now it appears to be working.Passing list(data) makes it access only the keys as it should right?